# Unexpected module 'CdkTableModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, module, angular-material2, angular-cdk

At first when I type `ng serve`, 2 directory `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk` were removed, I correct the problem but now I have another.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {CdkTableModule} from '@angular/cdk';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CdkTableModule,
    AppComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    BodyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please use the angular tag for Angular 2+ questions and the angularjs tag for angular 1.x questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CdkTableModule` goes in the `imports` array because it is a module, and not a component.

Comment: It's not so bad once you get accustomed to how it works. I much prefer it over AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

From @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.11 CdkTableModule was moved to @angular/cdk/table

> import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';

Earlier versions of material 2 might not work as expected with Angular 4
Take care that it's DataSource is located in the same module:

> import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';

And that MdSort from @angular/material module does not provide the mdSortChange event yet

> // this.sort.mdSortChange